# How to deploy Java web application project from Eclipse to live Tomcat server?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, deployment

I have developed an web application using HTML, Java Servlet and all. While developing I was using Tomcat to deploy it in order to test it.

Now my development is done and I want to make it live. For that we have live server but as I am new to all this I dont know how to deploy my java web application on live server?

So please help me if you know to answer?

My Project Structure

```
     ProjectName
         ->src
               ->beanClass
                       ->class1
                       ->Class2
               ->easyServlet    
                       ->Servlet1
                       ->Servlet2
                       ->Servlet3
               ->easyTrans
                       ->Class1    
                       ->Class2    
                       ->Class3    
                       ->Class4    
         ->build
         ->WebContent
               ->META-INF
                       ->MENIFEST.mf
               ->WEB-INF
                       ->lib(contain javascript files)
                       ->web.xml
               ->html1
               ->html2
               ->html3
               ->html4
               ->html5
```

I am also using MySql so what I have to about it..

Comment: is a build process in place? do you have access to the file system of the file server?

Comment: @Mattan With "live server" I mean that we have server on which we have deployed our website and which is live and i want to deploy my application to the same server

Comment: @cularis Sorry, I am not able to understand what you are saying. I have develop my web application using EClipse IDE and I have used tomcat 6.0 as runtime environment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. You will have to build a WAR of the project.
   You can do this

   - in eclipse: right click on the project, Click "Export", and choose war file in the dialog (and mention, the destination, name and all)
   - via ant using the [war](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) task

     The ant option is better because when you have multiple developers on the project and the code is in version control, it is easier to get the project automatically (using ant) and build a war. (you have version control, don't you?)

   But this is more of an *operational* difference (albeit an important one) but the war created in either way are same
2. Deploy the war to the server

   - You can manually copy the war file to the $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps directory (See the "Creating and Deploying a WAR File" section on [this article](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/tomcat.html?page=5))
   - You can use the Tomcat 6 ["Manager" application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

**Update**
You said that you are using MySql also. MySql should be installed on a server (it *can* be on the same server) and the configuration should be changed (username, password, server details) so that the application connects to the same database (I am sure you are not hard coding database details and credentials in your application and reading them from some configuration, this is the configuration that has to be changed)

Comment: thanks, I think i got all the detail what I need.. Now last question as I developed my application using tomcat so is it necessary to deploy it using tomcat? can't I use JBOSS or Apache?

Comment: @mahesh You can deploy to JBOSS (but not to the Apache server, if that is what you mean by "Apache". Apache server is a simple HTTP server, you cannot have a _Java Web Application_ (one using servlets etc) hosted on it). Migration from Tomcat should not be difficult, and mostly (for simple apps) you will have to just copy the war file  to the $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy directory.

Comment: @mahesh However, developing in one server and deploying in another may lead to problems in the long run, especially when your application grows. An initial migration, from tomcat to Jboss is ok, but then after your development should also be on JBoss.

Comment: for the step 1. Creating the War file, is there a difference between eclipse right click and the jar -cvf command ? I'm asking because the two methods don't result in the same deployment for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554449/whats-the-different-between-jar-cvf-my-web-app-war-and-eclipse-export-as-war

Answer (score 3):

> For that we have live server but as I am new to all this I dont know how to deploy my java web application on live server?

I assume by this you meant , you have a public IP assigned to a server. Now you can install tomcat into this server and open the tomcat port for public and you will be able to access.

Now build a war file of your webapplication and put it into web-apps dir of the tomcat and start the server

Comment: thanks, You understand my point. But how to build war file of my application?. Also my application uses MySql so what I have to about it. I m using Eclipse

Comment: well it depends a lot on the project structure. if your project  is ant based then you might have ant script build.xml configured to do this . check for it.

Comment: Also my application uses MySql so what I have to about it

Comment: you need a mysql server installed too somewhere and make your web app able to communicate with it

Comment: I add my project structure in my que. And can I install mysql to my server?? may be its foolish que but I am doing this first time..

Comment: You can. but dedicated mysql server which isn't live would be better and safe.

Comment: @JigarJoshi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1048/discussion-between-mahesh-and-org-life-java-jigar-joshi)

Comment: I waited there. Don't see you online. timeout :)

Comment: initially I waited their and then I thought you won't come so I left room, anyways thnks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Making a few assumptions here. You need

1. A tomcat instance running on your production server
2. Permissions to make changes to the tomcat instance
3. A war file that bundles your application

If you have both, then you need to navigate to the Tomcat manager page and follow the instructions to upload your war file.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the war to the server

You can manually copy the war file to the `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` directory.

You can use the Tomcat 6 "Manager" application.