# How to upload java website with mysql on live server

Tags: java, mysql, upload, web, server

I am new in web development, please help about the uploading the java website on live server with mysql database.Please tell all the steps.

Comment: Check this link->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546430/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-on-live-server

Comment: `Uploading` isn't really uploading its `deploying` an app on live server

Answer (score 1):

It you want to test your application on live server.

Try it with [Jelastic](https://jelastic.com/public-cloud-free-trial/), a free trial for 2-weeks which gives you better understanding on deploying and testing your java web application on live server.

**Unrelated**
If you are using [JBoss Application Server 7](http://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads/), deploy your application over LAN network (deploy on 1 system and access from any other device)

- Export your application in EAR or WAR from IDE
- Just copy and paste you WAR/EAR file in deployment path like(D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments)
- open cmd, change directory to bin folder of JBossAS7
- Write command `standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0`
- Access your application like: http://192.168.1.9:8080/YourApplication

Obviously put your own PC's ip over here. Hoped helped. It gives you an Idea of hosting

Answer (score 0):

To deploy java on live server
firstly convert your java project to war file. Then rename it to root.war.Now open the tomcat manager provided by hosting service provider.Browse the root.war file and deploy it.
Secondly,for mysql db... Create mydb.sql file.Now go to your cpanel and create the database .And after that add the username and pass to myconnection utility java program.Now in cpanel go to phpmyadmin ,Click on the db created and import the mydb.sql created.And now you have successfully deployed the java project.